# Change object's field in type cast C++

Tags: c++, casting

**Problem**: when write type cast operator for object, i want to change state of object's field, who calls cast-operation.

**Question**: how can i change state of field in object, which one call cast operator?

Example below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class myClass {
public:
    int field;
    int res;
    myClass() { field = 0; res = -1; }
    operator bool() {
        field = 0;
        return static_cast<bool>(res);
    }
    myClass operator>(int val) {
        if (field > val) {
            res = 1;
        }
        else {
            res = 0;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    myClass example;
    example.field = 10;
    bool conRes = static_cast<bool>(example > 5);
    return 0;
}
```

But field doesn't change, cause in cast operator will sending copy of object:

```
test add before cast: 0000000A7BAFF6C8
test add bool() cast: 0000000A7BAFF7C4
test add after cast: 0000000A7BAFF6C8
```

Comment: Your `operator>` overload returns a copy of your object, which your `operator bool` then modifies.  Return by reference from `operator>` if you want to modify the object that was compared.  You shouldn't do this though.  It would be highly unexpected behavior for a comparison or conversion operator to modify the object it's called on.

Comment: @MilesBudnek i fully understand, that `operator>` prefer return bool value. This example fully scientific and educational and does not claim to be used in an industrial project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is in the return type you have chosen for `operator >`. You are returning a new instance of `myClass`. If you would like the result to act as the original class, you should return a reference to it instead. This is done by changing the return type to include `&`.

```
myClass operator>(int val)
return *this; // return a copy of this object

myClass& operator>(int val)
return *this; // return a reference to this object
```

In your code, with this change the reference `myClass&` returned will give direct access to `example` and you should see that `field` will be set to 0 during the cast operator call.

If you are familiar with objects in other programming languages C++ may be different in this way. `myClass` is a new object, but there are two ways to gain access to the object from another name alias.

- `myClass&` is a reference, which simply becomes another name for a `myClass` that existed before it.
- `myClass*` is a pointer, which may also access an existing `myClass`. However, unlike a reference, the pointer can be reassigned, and changed to point at a different `myClass`.

So, references are used when you need an alias to access one specific object. Pointers are used when you want to access different objects over time. A pointer that is never reassigned is similar in capability to a reference.

Comment: Yes! Thanks! I forget, that i need to used reference to returning type, if i want to use nested methods, thanks a lot

Comment: you should NOT use the > operator for this. That is a comparison operator and it is expected by code users that > return a bool and performs a comparison. if you want to do something else create your own function.

this has nothing to do with nested methods either.  This has to do with not creating a new object when you aren't trying to create a new object.  You need to return by reference if you want to return a reference.

it is also bad practice for the cast operator to be non-const and to modify internals.  it should be return a bool representation and nothing else.  read the C++faq

Comment: This is clearly not meant to be production code. For the purposes of exploring how C++ works, overloading operators in weird ways like this and inspecting their function can be very instructive. It's bizarre looking, but it seems to demonstrate a want to know the complex nature of C++ operator overloading. (So yes, "never" do this, but also... do this.)

Comment: Thanks @rainwarrior for understand my purporse to ask this question. I really like to discovery some non-obvious features of C++, like this.

Comment: And @UpAndAdam, please read my comment above, that i use this sample for  scientific and educational purpose, cause i know about best practise for C++.

Comment: This only demonstrates you dont have the understanding of the language you claim to have. If you knew about best practices you would have solved the problem yourself and wouldnt need to have asked the question. You clearly don't. This isn't tinkering that leads to anything intersting, it leads to someone reading this and thinking THIS IS A GOOD IDEA I SHOULD DO THIS. Learning about overloading functions has nothing do with casting and modifying things.  It's not a non-obvious feature its a very obvious feature that everyone agrees you shouldn't do by convention. so what did you learn? nothing.